# Proof of McDiarmid's inequality

Tags: probability, analysis

I'm trying to understand a proof of McDiarmid's inequality that appears in the appendix of the book *Foundations of Machine Learning*.[image]

What do the expressions in the red rectangle mean?  As I understand conditional expectation, the stuff to the right of the vertical line should define a sigma algebra. What does it mean to put $x$ next to some random variables and then take the supremum over $x$?

Comment: My best guess is that it is the conditional expectation given $X_k = x$, in the sense of disintegration.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks, so you think it means $\sup_x \int E[f(S)|X_1,...,X_{k-1}] d\mu_x$?

Comment: where $\mu_x$ is gotten via $X_k$ and the disintegration theorem?